# config server dns with ec2 amazon

Tags: amazon-ec2, bind, amazon-web-services

I have an instance mic with ubuntu 10.04 installed without problems, super fast for me, the problem is that I want to install Virtualmin being discharged to go my new sites. When I configure bind to generate the nameservers (ns, ns2) first I can not change the hostname for a FQDN and not see the option to change it. The assigned IP and bind the name generated for areas not applicable (I am new to this set also bind and areas).

Amazon ec2 The truth is great, great but the set is a bit messy, someone who was able to install and configure bind9 bind9 with Virtualmin or alone, there is a manual for this. I need someone who has been there can help me.

If no solution at the end I will have a conventional vps and would be a shame because amazon is great.

The configuration is generated bind this.

```
$ttl 38400
@   IN  SOA ip-10-243-63-218. root.ip-10-243-63-218. (
1330564129
10800
3600
604800
38400 )
@   IN  NS  ip-10-243-63-218.
ubuhive.com.    IN  A   10.243.63.218
www.ubuhive.com.    IN  A   10.243.63.218
ftp.ubuhive.com.    IN  A   10.243.63.218
m.ubuhive.com.  IN  A   10.243.63.218
localhost.ubuhive.com.  IN  A   127.0.0.1
webmail.ubuhive.com.    IN  A   10.243.63.218
admin.ubuhive.com.  IN  A   10.243.63.218
mail.ubuhive.com.   IN  A   10.243.63.218
ubuhive.com.    IN  MX  5 mail.ubuhive.com.
ubuhive.com.    IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:ubuhive.com ip4:10.243.63.218 ?all"

ubuhive.com.    IN  NS  ns.ubuhive.com.
ubuhive.com.    IN  NS  ns2.ubuhive.com.
ns.ubuhive.com. IN  A   xx.xx.xx.xx
ns2.ubuhive.com.    IN  A   xx.xx.xx.xx

The doubts I have are that it should go here:
@   IN  SOA ip-10-243-63-218. root.ip-10-243-63-218.
@   IN  NS  ip-10-243-63-218.

10.243.63.218 internal ip
xx.xx.xx.xx is my ip elastic
```

Regards

Comment: Its really hard to see what your question is. Please make this clearer or it is liable to be closed.

Comment: Sounds like machine translation to me. Hard to understand.

Comment: There are defiantly plenty of people who have installed DNS servers in the amazon cloud. But like Sam said, not really sure what your question is so I can't really help out too much.

Comment: Sorry for my english :(
What i need is to configure bind with amazon ec2, what is the best way to configure it, a tutorial to do the best possible way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I left out a lot of your records because it really isn't important to the question. I also haven't configured a slave server. Since it seems you're kind of new using bind we need to start with the basics. Once you get the basics working you can try to implement your working solution. Tested this solution with Amazon Linux you might need to change some directories using ubuntu i'm not sure.

For this configuration you'll use two files

1. /etc/named.conf
2. /var/named/master.ubuhive.com

Contents of /etc/named.conf

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost; };
    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
};

logging {
    channel default_debug {
            file "data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

zone "ubuhive.com" {
    type master;
    file "master.ubuhive.com";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
```

Contents of /var/named/master.ubuhive.com ( replace xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with your private ip )

```
$TTL 43200
ubuhive.com.     IN      SOA    help.ubuhive.com. ns01.ubuhive.com. (
                            1 ; serial
                            21600      ; refresh (6 hours)
                            7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                            1209600    ; expire (2 weeks)
                            43200)      ; minimum (12 hours)

ubuhive.com.            NS      ns01.ubuhive.com.
ns01                    A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Now locally you can run the command `host ns01.ubuhive.com 127.0.0.1`

```
[root@domU-12-31-39-09-FA-A8 ~]# host ns01.ubuhive.com 127.0.0.1
Using domain server:
Name: 127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
Aliases:

ns01.ubuhive.com has address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Let me know if you're still having problems or if this configuration isn't doing what you expected.